# Specifying Pump Max RPM

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

I am reviewing specifications that indicate: "Pump Maximum Speed, RPM (Estimated, manufacturer to recommend): 187". Another paragraph later on indicates the following: "Rotative speed of pump must be no greater than 400 rpm."

This appears to be a contradiction. However, it has me wondering what is the usefulness of specifying a maximum rotative speed. Is this to prevent undesired vibrations? Could there be any drawbacks to strictly forbidding pumps from operating above a certain RPM (besides being unable to provide the necessary lift)?

Comment: No contradiction found unless you manage to equate " (inches?) And RPM.  Inches are likely inches of water (or whatever fluid) indicating head.  There are limits on how hard and how fast you can run something.

Comment: I don't think he made any reference to inches. There's quotation marks

Comment: Whoops yup just quotes.  Still no contradiction. 
 Then the difference is in the "estimated, manufacturer to recommend" the 400 imposes a restriction on the manufacturer suggestion.  Manufacturer then would have to be whoever determined where the pump is to be used probably based on loading, power source, and hopefully testing.

Comment: Pump speeds are matched to motor or motor/sheave specs

Comment: Abel, I believe you are correct that this is the purpose of the language seen. I am curious as to why such a restriction on the manufacturer suggestion would be imposed?

Answer (score 1):

If spun faster than a certain threshold, the water flowing over a pump impeller will fail to follow the blade contours and the blades will stall. This is called *cavitation* and while cavitating, the pump is performing little useful work and is moving very little fluid. Pumps must be operated below the cavitation point, which might be what the pump spec is referring to.

Comment: I understand that if there is cavitation occurring that increasing the speed of the vanes will intensify the damage due to said cavitation. Is including an estimated maximum speed and a hard limit to maximum speed really required? It seems as though if this is the concern that the easier way of writing the specs would be to include language requiring pump manufacturer to ensure cavitation will not occur with the submittal of the design to the owner prior to prototyping and testing. Upon receival of prototype, if the owner believes there is a maximum RPM limit, they could comment at that stage.